# what's the best way to hardcode a multiple-line string?

Tags: string, f#, multilinestring

In unit test I would like to hard code a block of lines as a string.

In C# I would do

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("myline1");
sb.AppendLine("myline2");
sb.AppendLine("myline3");
```

Since I converted to F# I tried to minimize the usage of .Net method by using `bprintf` instead, but somehow there is no `bprintfn` support which seems strange to me.

It is tedious to add `\r\n` at the end of each line manually.

Or is there any better way than `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Nowadays in C# we would use `@""` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is no problem with using `StringBuilder` in F# as you did.

There is a function `fprintfn` in [Printf module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx), so you can use it with a `StringWriter` object:

```
let sw = new StringWriter()
fprintfn sw "myline1"
fprintfn sw "myline2"
fprintfn sw "myline3"
sw.ToString()
```

I like `fprintf` and `fprintfn` since they are flexible. You can write to console output by supplying `stdout` instead.

Answer (score 107):

Little known feature: you can indeed indent string content - by ending each line with a backslash.  Leading spaces on the following line are stripped:

```
let poem = "The lesser world was daubed\n\
            By a colorist of modest skill\n\
            A master limned you in the finest inks\n\
            And with a fresh-cut quill.\n"
```

You will still need to include `\n` or `\n\r` at line ends though (as done in the example above), if you want these embedded in your final string.

Edit to answer @MiloDCs question:

To use with sprintf:

```
let buildPoem character =
    sprintf "The lesser world was daubed\n\
             By a colorist of modest skill\n\
             A master limned %s in the finest inks\n\
             And with a fresh-cut quill.\n" character

buildPoem "you"            
buildPoem "her"
buildPoem "him"
```

Comment: Good tip @Kit--that's a new one to me too.

Comment: I don't like this approach because I guess it wouldn't use the platform-agnostic `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: How to do this with sprintf?

Comment: @MiloDC Edited to answer your question. ;-)

Comment: With sprintf, I get an error when using formatters. `sprintf "foo %s bar,\n\ ` then on the other line: `foobar %s\n." "a" "b"` (with indentation) is getting me `expecting a string -> a -> b  but  given a string -> string`. EDIT : wait, it compiles and work fine! The error is only in Visual Studio editor! Looks like a VS bug.

Answer (score 56):

If you are under F# 3.0, triple-quoted strings may be the answer:

```
let x = """
myline1
myline2
myline3"""
```

Comment: caveat with that approach is that you must "clip" the string lines at the beginning of line, otherwise the indentation spaces will be taken into the string. It looks a bit ugly when you have indented code,

Answer (score 15):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this:

```
[ "My first line"
  "second line"
  "another line" ]
|> String.concat "\n"
```

Comment: it is basically the same as @jellyfish 's method, but looks extremely useful under such formatting.

Comment: this is IMO how triple quotes should have worked. If you want to write pretty code with triple quotes as it is now it just screws up the indentation.

Answer (score 10):

You can create directly multi-line string literals in F#:

```
let multiLineStr = 
  "myline1
myline2
myline3"
```

and C#:

```
var multiLineStr =
  @"myline1
myline2
myline3";
```

Comment: One drawback of this is, that you cannot indent the string content which looks bad.

Comment: The `@` prefix can also be used in F#.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own `bprintfn` function:

```
let bprintfn bldr fmt =
  (bldr, fmt) ||> Printf.kbprintf bldr.AppendLine
```

Or, to define a multi-line literal you could use triple-quotes as bytebuster suggested or a "verbatim literal," which begins with `@` (see [Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829.aspx)).

Comment: I think this gives `myline1myline2myline3` - without the end lines

Answer (score 0):

I'm out of touch with F#, but you might be able to do adapt my normal approach:

```
['line1', 'line2', 'line3'].join('\n'); //javascript

StringUtils.join(Arrays.asList("line1", "line2", "line3"), "\n")); // java, using Apache Commons Lang
```